# How to check that a symbol is defined in linker script

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I am using different linker script. In some, a value is defined, in others, it is not defined:

```
DIRECTORY_ADDRESS = 0x80100000;
DIRECTORY_SIZE = 32M;
```

At execution, I want a default behavior when this value is not defined, and a special behavior when it is defined.

Classically, I get the values like this:

```
extern void * DIRECTORY_ADDRESS;
extern void * DIRECTORY_SIZE;

void f() { 
  void *dir_addr = &DIRECTORY_ADDRESS;
  int dir_size   = (int)&DIRECTORY_SIZE;
}
```

My first lead to conditionnaly execute code according to the existence of this value in linker script is the weak atttribute:

```
extern void * DIRECTORY_ADDRESS  __attribute__ ((weak)) = 0x0;
extern void * DIRECTORY_SIZE __attribute__ ((weak)) = 0x0;

void f() {
  if ( DIRECTORY_ADDRESS )
    // special code
  else
    // default code
}
```

But it can't work, as I am initializing the pointer value, and not its address: even an undifined weak symbol has an address. So directory address is always != NULL.

I am pretty sure this problem has already been solved, but I can't find any related problem on the web.

Comment: Can you just used shared libraries and check for failure to load the lib with your func in it?

Answer (score 2):

My mistake!

I tried many combination, and this one is actually wrong:

As I am initliazing weak symbols, there are "half weak"

```
extern void * DIRECTORY_ADDRESS  __attribute__ ((weak)) = 0x0;
extern void * DIRECTORY_SIZE __attribute__ ((weak)) = 0x0;
```

To solve my problem, I just have to let weak symbols uninitialized, then the symbol address will be NULL if they are not defined with a strong symbol:

```
extern void * DIRECTORY_ADDRESS  __attribute__ ((weak));
extern void * DIRECTORY_SIZE __attribute__ ((weak));
```

Comment: They are not really "half weak"; weak symbols do have a default value.

Answer (score 2):

Uninitialized globals are weak by default, so you can just use

```
void * DIRECTORY_ADDRESS;
void * DIRECTORY_SIZE;
```

If there is no external symbol defined for these names, the value will default to NULL.  To force a different default value than NULL, you could use

```
void * DIRECTORY_ADDRESS __attribute__ ((weak)) = OTHER_VALUE;
void * DIRECTORY_SIZE __attribute__ ((weak)) = OTHER_VALUE;
```

Note that *initializing an `extern`* doesn't really make sense: `extern` means that the definition is external to the file, but initializing provides a definition.  My compiler (gcc 4.4) *warns* the user of this, and then ignores the `extern` modifier.  This means your example worked as expected for me (even when initializing to 0x0), but maybe your compiler handles this ambiguous situation differently.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I explain in my self-answer. Actually, the initialization of the weak symbol was one of the debugging step, it has nothing to do here!